# How to get lex attribute in amazon connect contact flow block?

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-lex

hi i am working on amazon lex and want to get NluIntentConfidence value in Contact flow **CheckAttribute** block.

[image]

I have tried using like this

[image]

but IVR is not checking this value So, anyone can help me with this how i can get this value?

have a look at the contact flow design.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect only allows you to use key/values returned inside "sessionAttributes" or slot values. As you can see from the response, nluIntentConfidence is not a session attribute, you cannot use it in connect.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/types-of-contact-attributes.html

To get this value in connect, I suggest you use a codehook, either validation or fulfillment codehook in lex to take his value and store it in lex session. You can then use it in connect contact flow. If you have not used it already, you can refer to below documentation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/using-lambda.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/ex-book-trip-create-integrate.html